# I am able to connect to the Oracle Database thru sql plus but not thru sql developer

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper, oracle-xe

I installed **Oracle11g XE for windows32**. 
**First time** when I try to connect via SQL developer it **gets connected** effortlessly. **But once I close the SQL Developer and restart it**, then again I am unable to connect to the DB. 
Then I tried to connect with SQL plus and guess what it gets connected! 
But through SQL devloper I receive an error message as follows:

ORA-12505, TNS:listener does not currently know of SID given in connect descriptor.

I have checked all the credentials thoroughly. Still am unable to find the error. Please Help.

Comment: Can you show some code?

Comment: @Dieter Meemken what code?

Comment: StackOverflow is a 'Q&A for professional and enthusiast programmers' site. If you tryed to connect by own code, then you should show it and we may help. Otherwise, may be you will have more luck asking on one of the other sites like ServerFault or DatabaseAdministrators...

Comment: But where do we need coding in just connecting to the DATABASE :-/ :-/

Comment: your connect string is wrong. what is the 'sid' or 'service' you have set for your connection? It should be 'xe'

Comment: How do you connect using `sqlplus`? Please show us the **exact** command line. And add the JDBC URL you are using for SQL Developer. And what is the message shown in SQL Plus after connecting? Are both Windows services (one for the instance one for the listener) running?

Answer (score 1):

When you are using `sql plus` you use the `tnsnames.ora` file to find your connection. You can do the same in `sql developer`.
Just click the listbox `connection type` and choose `TNS` instead of `basic`
then for network alias you should be able to choose a connection from your tnsnames.ora